# DRY swipe navigation in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am putting some JQuery swipe navigation on a project developed with Jquery Mobile. I can get it to work no worries but it is not a DRY implementation and I know I'm going to have issues updating it in the future. What I have is a series of HTML pages that swipe navigate to other HTML pages in the same folder. Here is an example of HTML code:

```
<div id="point2" class="tpb" data-role="page" data-title="Baby Section - Talking Point 2">
  <header data-role="header" data-theme="f" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-theme="h" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
      <a href="../activities.html" data-theme="h" data-icon="baby">Activities</a>
      <h1>0-12 Months</h1>
  </header>
  <div data-role="content" class="content" data-theme="a">
   <h1>Mother&rsquo;s Voice</h1>
   <p>Babies learn to recognise their mother&rsquo;s voice in utero. By birth your baby has a preference for your voice over other sounds. Babies also begin to learn the difference between sounds not long after birth.</p>
<p>Talk to your baby often and from birth. Use their name, talk about whatever you are doing and repeat words many times. Babies need to hear words lots of times before they understand and use them.</p>
    <p><img src="../../img/baby/Baby-TP2-Mothers-Voice.jpg" class="insert" /></p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#point2").on('swipeleft', function (event, ui) {
   if(event.handled !== true){
    $.mobile.changePage('point3.html', {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
       event.handled = true;
   }
    return false; 
});
$("#point2").on('swiperight', function (event, ui) {
   if(event.handled !== true){
    $.mobile.changePage('point1.html', {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
       event.handled = true;
   }
    return false; 
}); 
</script>
</div>
```

Now I have tried to follow the JQuery Mobile documentation for doing this the DRY way and the docs make no sense to me at all. It appears as though all the sample does is swap a div that has a different background image. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html

I am confident I can get DRY working if all the pages were in a single HTML file that all loads into the DOM (single page app) but I am working with separate files? I am just wondering if I can set up an array to pick up sequential pages in the folder and keep a certain order? My JS skills are not so great so I'm looking for a working example to pick apart so I can understand its implementation. Please let me know if you have any good implementations for this. I want to be DRY!!

Comment: DRY in _single page model_ might not be achievable, as you need to load all libraries and - maybe - code in each html page. Assuming a user bypasses home page (page1) directly to another page (pageX), if main libraries aren't loaded, the page will fail.

Comment: Thanks Omar, that's what I thought. The code was pretty DRY before when I had them in a single page model but after code review, I was told to separate them as it was bloating the DOM model. Then they tell me to make it DRY! Cheeky muttons...